# No funciona Disabled en el controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando una aplicación web en c# asp.net mvc5, tengo un dropdown dependiente que se carga a través de una función **javascript** y los datos son de la **base de datos**. A este `dropdown` deseo ponerle un texto **--Seleccione--**, y a su vez que este texto salga **Deshabilitado**, pero hasta ahora no consigo que funcione el Disabled.

**Controller**

```
var municQuery = db.n_municipio.Where(c => c.id_provincia == id).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> munic = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in municQuery)

        {
            munic.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = item.id_municipio.ToString(),
                Text = item.municipio,

            });
        }// foreach

        munic.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "0", 
        Text = "--Seleccione--", Disabled = true });

return Json(munic, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

El dropdown se carga sin problemas no importa la forma en que lo envie a la vista pero no me sale `Disabled`. Cuando traceo o debbugeo el código, si embargo me sale `true`.

**La vista**

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $("#provincia").change(function () {
        $("#id_municipio").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("MunicipioByProvinciaTwo", "Municipio")', // we are calling json method

            dataType: 'json',

            data: { id: $("#provincia").val() },

            success: function (CityMunicipio) {
                  $.each(CityMunicipio, function (i, CityMunic) {
                    $("#id_municipio").append('<option value="' + CityMunic.Value + '">' +
                     CityMunic.Text + '</option>');
                  });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Municipio.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
      })
   });
</script>
```

```
@Html.DropDownList("id_municipio", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Seleccione un municipio")
```

Yo utilizo la misma vista para el GET y el POST, por eso en el dropdown de abajo el **Seleccione** se ve antes del submit y luego se ve el **Seleccione** que esta en el controller.
Qué puedo estar haciendo mal. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Veo que estás generando dos veces la opción por default, primero en el Controller y luego en el View al llenar el `DropDownList`. Al ver tu código supongo que llenas ese `DropDownList` desde una petición Ajax, para lo cual sugiero que deshabilites la opción por default con Javascript o jQuery una vez que obtengas los datos en la vista.

Comment: Pudieras agregar tu función de JavaScript que carga tu select-option, por favor?

Comment: Favor de [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código Javascript.

Comment: @KodiakMx, Flxtr y davlio, ya edite mi pregunta y le agregue el codigo javascript, espero que con esto me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que finalmente, el `DrowDownList` se va a renderear en el Html de la siguiente manera:

```
<select id="id_municipio" name="id_municipio">
    <option value="0">--Seleccione--</option>
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
</select>
```

La solución la puedes manejar con jQuery, justo después de llenar los datos:

```js
$("select option[value='0']").prop('disabled',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id_municipio" name="id_municipio">
    <option value="0">--Seleccione--</option>
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
</select>
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $("#provincia").change(function () {
        $("#id_municipio").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("MunicipioByProvinciaTwo", "Municipio")', // we are calling json method

            dataType: 'json',

            data: { id: $("#provincia").val() },

            success: function (CityMunicipio) {
                  $.each(CityMunicipio, function (i, CityMunic) {
                    $("#id_municipio").append('<option value="' + CityMunic.Value + '">' +
                     CityMunic.Text + '</option>');
                  });
                  $("select option[value='0']").prop('disabled',true);
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Municipio.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
      })
   });
</script>
```

Comment: No sería solo usar `$("select#id_municipio option[value='0']").prop('disabled',true);`, para que no afecte a los demás `select`.

Comment: @Flxtr gracias por tu ayuda, funciono OK, y a ti tamben Davlio